# register component in nuxt as shadowdom without using any third party library

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to register my component as shadowdom in Vue when creating new Vue component from Vue instance you can attach shadowdom but in nuxt i`m confused .

Comment: How do you make this in Vue?

Comment: @kissu https://gitlab.com/dmishunov/vue-in-shadow-dom here explained how to do it in vue